# Python 3.5 [with tkinter buttons]

Tags: tkinter

I'm new in Py 3.5 and I didn't find any answers to my question on the web.
In Pycharm, when I create  a button with tkinter, it adds it to the pane and everything works fine. However, if I try to create a second button, I won't show up. What's the issue ? Thanks, here's my code :

```
import tkinter

fen = tkinter.Tk()
fen.title('Bataille Navale')
fen.geometry('943x511')

def callback():
    print ("Fin du jeu!")
    exit()
def callback2():
    print ("Aide!")

quitter = tkinter.Button(fen, text="Quitter", command=callback)
quitter.grid(padx=720, pady=400)

aide = tkinter.Button(fen, text="Aide", command=callback2)
aide.grid()

fen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's on the window, you just can't see it because you've placed it outside the visible area of the window.

You've added a padding of 720x400 for the first button, so the second button is going to be below that, roughly at y coordinate 721. You've specified a window size that is only 511 pixels tall.